# Produce a time line plot with specific draw

Tags: r, ggplot2

Inserting this data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018), value = c(337,423,551,661,846,1387,2222,3580))
```

How is it possible to produce a line plot like this using the df data?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f3SP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Text placement relative to the points can be a bit finnicky.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018), 
                 value = c(337,423,551,661,846,1387,2222,3580))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, y = (value - 50)*0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks. The background option of the plot how is it possible to be made like the one in the picture?

Comment: You can add `+ theme_minimal() + theme(...)` where the first bit sets a minimal theme and you can tweak the appearance of many theme elements where I've put `...`. Check out `?theme` for the arguments.

Comment: thank you once more. Is there any option to change the color of the numbers?

Comment: Yes you can add `, color = "blue"` after the `aes(label = ...)` or whatever colour you like. However, there are also plenty of examples and documentation that can show you how to do these things.